# PyTorch, PPO with LSTM doesn't train with episode trajectory

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, reinforcement-learning

I'm studying reinforcement learning.
this code causes some problem.
When it runs train() function, its policy and value function outputs are all Nan.
Here's my code which run an simple environment, Cartpole.

It's import setting.

```
import gym
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.distributions import Categorical
```

It's hyper parameter.

```
learning_rate = 0.0005
gamma = 0.98
lmbda = 0.95
K = 3
epsilon = 0.1
```

It's agent code which is used PPO and LSTM.

```
class PPO_lstm(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super(PPO_lstm, self).__init__()
    self.log_list = []

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(4, 32) # state encoder, value and policy function use it
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(32, 64) # LSTM, value and policy function use it
    self.fc2_pi = nn.Linear(64, 2) # policy function 
    self.fc2_v = nn.Linear(64, 1) # value function
    self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

  def pi(self, x, hidden_state):  # get policy
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)) # x size : [32] or [batch, 32]
    x = x.view(1, -1, 32) # x size : [1, batch, 32]
    x, new_hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden_state) # x size : [1, batch, 64]
    x = x.squeeze(0) # x size : [batch, 64]
    pi = F.log_softmax(self.fc2_pi(x), dim=1)
    return pi, new_hidden # pi size : [batch, 2], new_hidden size : [1, batch, 64]

  def v(self, x, hidden_state):  # get state value
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x)) # x size : [32] or [batch, 32]
    x = x.view(1, -1, 32) # x size : [1, batch, 32]
    x, new_hidden = self.lstm(x, hidden_state) # x size : [1, batch, 64]
    x = x.squeeze(0) # x size : [batch, 64]
    v = self.fc2_v(x) # v size : [batch, 1]
    return v # v size : [batch, 1]

  def add_log(self, log):  # add transition which used train function
    self.log_list.append(log) # s, a, r, s', action_prob, done, hidden(h, c), hidden_prime(h, c)

  def make_batch(self): # make batch file using log_list for training
    s_lst, a_lst, r_lst, s_prime_lst, prob_a_lst, done_lst, h_h_lst, h_c_lst, h_prime_h_lst, h_prime_c_lst = [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
    for i in self.log_list:
      s, a, r, s_prime, done, action_prob, h, h_prime = i

      s_lst.append(s) # s_lst size : [batch, 4]
      a_lst.append([a]) # a_lst size : [batch, 1]
      r_lst.append([r]) # r_lst size : [batch, 1]
      s_prime_lst.append(s_prime) # s_prime_lst size : [batch, 4]
      prob_a_lst.append([action_prob]) # prob_a_lst size : [batch, 1]
      done_lst.append([0 if done else 1]) # done_lst size : [batch, 1]
      h_h, h_c = h # hidden_h, hidden_c size : [1, 1, 64]
      h_h_lst.append(h_h.detach().numpy()) # hidden1_c_lst size : [batch] inside : [1, 1, 64]
      h_c_lst.append(h_c.detach().numpy()) # hidden1_h_lst size : [batch] inside : [1, 1, 64]
      h_prime_h, h_prime_c = h_prime
      h_prime_h_lst.append(h_prime_h.detach().numpy()) # hidden2_c_lst size : [batch] inside : [1, 1, 64]
      h_prime_c_lst.append(h_prime_c.detach().numpy()) # hidden2_h_lst size : [batch] inside : [1, 1, 64]

    s_lst = torch.tensor(s_lst, dtype=torch.float)    
    a_lst = torch.tensor(a_lst)    
    r_lst = torch.tensor(r_lst)    
    s_prime_lst = torch.tensor(s_prime_lst, dtype=torch.float)    
    prob_a_lst = torch.tensor(prob_a_lst, dtype=torch.float)    
    done_lst = torch.tensor(done_lst)
    h_h_lst = torch.tensor(h_h_lst, dtype=torch.float).squeeze().unsqueeze(0)
    h_c_lst = torch.tensor(h_c_lst, dtype=torch.float).squeeze().unsqueeze(0)
    h_prime_h_lst = torch.tensor(h_prime_h_lst, dtype=torch.float).squeeze().unsqueeze(0)
    h_prime_c_lst = torch.tensor(h_prime_c_lst, dtype=torch.float).squeeze().unsqueeze(0) # size : [1, batch, 64]

    self.log_list = []
    return s_lst, a_lst, r_lst, s_prime_lst, prob_a_lst, done_lst, h_h_lst, h_c_lst, h_prime_h_lst, h_prime_c_lst
```

it's train function which used batch (s, a, r, s', done, hidden, hidden')

```
  def train(self):
    s, a, r, s_prime, prob_a, done_mask, h_h, h_c, h_prime_h, h_prime_c = self.make_batch()

    h = (h_h.detach(), h_c.detach()) # h size : ([1, batch, 64], [1, batch, 64])
    h_prime = (h_prime_h.detach(), h_prime_c.detach()) # h_prime size : ([1, batch, 64], [1, batch, 64])

    for k in range(K): # PPO Algo. K iteration 
      td_target = r + gamma * self.v(s_prime, h_prime) * done_mask # td_target size : [batch, 1]
      delta = td_target - self.v(s, h) # 기존 Advantage : Q(s, a) - V(s) == delta : r + gamma * V(s') - V(s)
      delta = delta.detach().numpy()

      advantage_lst = [] # GAE
      advantage = 0.0
      for delta_t in delta[::-1]:
        advantage = gamma * lmbda * advantage + delta_t[0] 
        advantage_lst.append([advantage])
      advantage_lst.reverse() # advantage_lst size : [batch, 1]
      advantage = torch.tensor(advantage_lst, dtype=torch.float)

      curr_pi, _ = self.pi(s, h) # curr_pi size : [batch, 2]
      curr_pi_a = curr_pi.gather(1, a) # curr_pi_a size : [batch, 2].gather(1, [batch, 1]) = [batch, 1]
      past_pi = prob_a # past_pi size : [batch, 1]
      ratio = torch.exp(torch.log(curr_pi_a) - torch.log(past_pi))  # a/b == exp(log(a)-log(b))
      # ratio size : [batch, 1]

      surr_1 = ratio * advantage
      surr_2 = torch.clamp(ratio, 1 - epsilon, 1 + epsilon) * advantage
      loss = -torch.min(surr_1, surr_2) + F.smooth_l1_loss(self.v(s, h), td_target.detach()) 
      # actor loss + critic loss

      self.optimizer.zero_grad()
      loss.mean().backward()
      self.optimizer.step()
```

and it's main function which run openAI Gym cartpole environment.

```
def main():
  env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
  agent = PPO_lstm()
  score = 0.0
  print_interval = 20

  for episode in range(10000):
    hidden = (torch.zeros([1, 1, 64], dtype=torch.float), torch.zeros([1, 1, 64], dtype=torch.float)) # lstm init hidden state
    s = env.reset()
    done = False
    while not done:
      for step in range(20):
        pi, hidden_prime = agent.pi(torch.from_numpy(s).float(), hidden) # pi size : [1, 2]
        pi = pi.squeeze() # pi size : [2]
        m = Categorical(pi)
        action = m.sample().item()
        s_prime, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
        agent.add_log((s, action, reward / 100.0, s_prime, pi[action].item(), done, hidden, hidden_prime))
        # hidden dim : ([1, 1, 64], [1, 1, 64])
        hidden = hidden_prime
        s = s_prime
        score += reward
        if done:
          break
      agent.train()
    if episode % print_interval == 0 and episode != 0:
      print("episode {}'s avg score : {}".format(episode, score/print_interval))
      score = 0.0

  env.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

When I try this code without LSTM(using MLP policy and value function), it runs well.
Can you tell me there are any problem using LSTM or hidden state?

Comment: did you made it work?